# conflict when extends interface with react-final-form FieldRenderProps in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form

#### Hi

I try to create custom react function component to pass it to
react-final-form Field as a component but get an error.

#### details

The Form

```
import {Form as FinalForm, Field} from 'react-final-form';
import { Form} from 'semantic-ui-react';

<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field placeholder='Venue' value={activity.venue} name={'TEST FIELD'} component={TestInput} />
</Form>
```

TestInput function component

```
import React from 'react';
import {FieldRenderProps} from "react-final-form";

const TestInput : React.FC<FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLInputElement>> = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      HI HI TEST
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now there is an error at 
`component={TestInput}` say that : ... type is not assignable to ... lab lab

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIjyo.png)

I know why this problem occurs, this because of the definition of component

```
component?: React.ComponentType<T> | SupportedInputs;
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

// Here : T extends => HTMLElement 
export interface FieldRenderProps<FieldValue, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement> {
  input: FieldInputProps<FieldValue, T>;
  meta: FieldMetaState<FieldValue>;
}
```

So why i can not use HtmlInputElelemnt Although its defention :

`interface HTMLInputElement extends HTMLElement`

Now when I replace HTMLInputElement with HtmlElement everything work correctly

```
const TestInput: React.FC<FieldRenderProps<string, HTMLElement>> = ({ }) =>
```

Now I just pass this by mark this line with `@ts-ignore`
to ignore it! but where is the problem?

#### Update

I Test this code on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leakey-gfz8b) but no errors at all
But with Visual studio code, visual studio, all JetBrains IDEs, the error still appear ???

Notice: This code also works for me but only when I use @ts-ignore

### Update [Partailly Solved]

I solve the problem, just remove `"strict": true` from `tsconfig.json` solve the problem!.

#### But

The Demo project [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-leakey-gfz8b) strict mode work without any problem ??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today; I downgraded the versions of `react-final-form` and `final-form` and now it's working. Probably it's just a bug or something.

`npm install react-final-form@6.3.0 final-form@4.16.1`

Those are the versions I'm using to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, you should not be specifying a `value` prop [unless you are using a radio button or a checkbox](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FieldProps#value).

What if you specify the field type in the `<Field/>` component like so?

```
<Field<string> 
//    ^^^^^^^^-------- LIKE THIS
  name={'TEST FIELD'}
  placeholder='Venue' 
  component={TestInput} />
```

That might help.

Comment: A CodeSandbox is worth a thousand words. Either you're doing something wrong, or you've found a bug, but a sandbox will clarify everything.

Comment: Ok, there is a problem , i run the same code on CodeSandbox.io but no errors , and this code execute errors with Visual studio , Visual Studio Code, And All jetbrains IDEs ?? , Also i Update the question with codeSandbox link